# std::map Requirements for Keys (Design Decision)

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, user-defined-types

When I make a `std::map<my_data_type, mapped_value>`, what C++ expects from me is that `my_data_type` has its own `operator<`.

```
struct my_data_type
{
    my_data_type(int i) : my_i(i) { }

    bool operator<(const my_data_type& other) const { return my_i < other.my_i; }

    int my_i;
};
```

The reason is that you can derive `operator>` and `operator==` from `operator<`. *b < a* implies *a > b*, so there's `operator>`. *!(a < b) && !(b < a)* means that *a* is neither less than *b* nor greater than it, so they must be equal.

The question is: Why hasn't the C++ designer require `operator==` to be explicitly defined? Obviously, `operator==` is inevitable for `std::map::find()` and for removing duplicates from the `std::map`. Why implement 5 operations and call a method twice in order not to compel me to explicitly implement `operator==`?

Comment: Many of your assumptions and assertions are not quite correct or based on facts, I'm afraid.

Comment: Btw, does that constructor work? Looks like a semantic error.

Comment: [@supertopi] You're right. I've edited it, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> `operator==` is inevitable for `std::map::find()`

This is where you go badly wrong. `map` does not use `operator==` at all, it is not "inevitable". Two keys `x` and `y` are considered equivalent for the purposes of the map if `!(x < y) && !(y < x)`.

`map` doesn't know or care whether you've implemented `operator==`. Even if you have, it need not be the case that all equivalent keys in the order are equal according to `operator==`.

The reason for all this is that wherever C++ relies on orders (sorting, maps, sets, binary searches), it bases everything it does on the well-understood mathematical concept of a "strict weak order", which is also defined in the standard. There's no particular need for `operator==`, and if you look at the code for these standard functions you won't very often see anything like `if (!(x < y) && !(y < x))` that does both tests close together.

Additionally, none of this is necessarily based on `operator<`. The default comparator for `map` is `std::less<KeyType>`, and that by default uses `operator<`. But if you've specialized `std::less` for `KeyType` then you needn't define `operator<`, and if you specify a different comparator for the map then it may or may not have anything to do with `operator<` or `std::less<KeyType>`. So where I've said `x < y` above, really it's `cmp(x,y)`, where `cmp` is the strict weak order.

This flexibility is another reason why not to drag `operator==` into it. Suppose `KeyType` is `std::string`, and you specify your own comparator that implements some kind of locale-specific, case-insensitive collation rules. If `map` used `operator==` some of the time, then that would completely ignore the fact that strings differing only by case should count as the same key (or in some languages: with other differences that are considered not to matter for collation purposes). So the equality comparison would *also* have to be configurable, but there would only be one "correct" answer that the programmer could provide. This isn't a good situation, you never want your API to offer something that looks like a point of customization but really isn't.

Besides, the concept is that once you've ruled out the section of the tree that's less than the key you're searching for, and the section of the tree for which the key is less than it, what's left either is empty (no match found) or else has a key in it (match found). So, you've already used `current < key` then `key < current`, leaving no other option but equivalence. The situation is exactly:

```
if (search_key < current_element)
    go_left();
else if (current_element < search_key)
    go_right();
else
    declare_equivalent();
```

and what you're suggesting is:

```
if (search_key < current_element)
    go_left();
else if (current_element < search_key)
    go_right();
else if (current_element == search_key)
    declare_equivalent();
```

which is obviously not needed. In fact, it's *your* suggestion that's less efficient!

Comment: [@Steve] *"If you look at the code for these standard functions you won't very often see anything like if (!(x < y) && !(y < x)) that does both tests close together"*. Then how is `std::map::find`  and removing the duplicates defined? I know I can take a look at the code, but I mean: What's the concept? Equality must be defined (in whatever form) to implement these two, and what's already done is less efficient than depending on an explicitly defined equality function. That's the main point I want to be convinced with.

Comment: @Omar: the concept is that once you've ruled out the section of the tree that's less than the key you're searching for, and the section of the tree for which the key is less than it, what's left either is empty (no match found) or else has a key in it (match found).

Answer (score 4):

Your assumptions aren't correct. Here's what's really happening:

`std::map` is a class template which takes four template parameters: key type `K`, mapped type `T`, comparator `Comp` and allocator `Alloc` (the names are immaterial, of course, and only local to this answer). What matters for this discussion is that an object `Comp comp;` can be called with two key refrences, `comp(k1, k2)`, where `k1` and `k2` are `K const &`, and the result is a boolean which imlpements a *strict weak ordering*.

If you do not specify the third argument, then `Comp` is the default type `std::less<K>`, and this (stateless) class imlpements the binary operation as `k1 < k2`. It does not matter whether this `<`-operator is a member of `K`, or a free function, or a template, or whatever.

And that wraps up the story, too. The comparator type is the *only* datum required to implement an ordered map. Equality is **defined** as `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b,a)`, and the map only stores one unique key according to this definition of equality.

There is no reason to make additional requirements on the key type, and also there is no logical reason that a user-defined `operator==` and `operator<` should at all be *compatible*. They could both exist, independently, and serve entirely different and unrelated purpose.

A good library imposes the minimal necessary requirements and offers the greatest possible amount of flexibility, and this is precisely what `std::map` does.

Comment: "Equality is defined as..."  Perhaps "equivalence" would be a better choice of words here.

Comment: All this is good, but my main point is: Not requiring `operator==` is _less efficient_! That's my main question (your last statement _partially_ answers this part, but I'm still not convinced enough because of the fact that almost all C++ design decisions were based on efficiency (besides backward compatibility with C)).

Comment: @Omar: That's a false assumption, as Tom Whittock's answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the element `i` within the map, we have traversed to element `e` the tree search will already have tested `i < e`, which would have returned false.

So either you call `i == e` or you call `e < i`, both of which imply the same thing given the prerequisite of finding `e` in the tree already. Since we already had to have an `operator<` we don't rely on `operator==`, since that would increase the demands of the key concept.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why a comparison operator is needed is the way map is implemented: as a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), which allows you to look up, insert and delete elements in `O(log n)`. In order to build this tree, a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) must be defined for the set of keys. That's why only one operator definition is needed.

Comment: The ordering defined by the predicate is required to be a strict weak order but not necessarily a total order.

Answer (score 1):

You have a faulty assumption:

> `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` means that a is neither less than b nor greater than it, so they must be equal.

It means that they are *equivalent*, but not necessarily *equal*. You are free to implement `operator<` and `operator==` in such a way that two objects can be equivalent but not equal.

> Why hasn't the C++ designer require `operator==` to be explicitly defined?

To simplify the implementation of types that can be used as keys, and to allow you to use a single custom comparator for types without overloaded operators. The only requirement is that you supply a comparator (either `operator<` or a custom functor) that defines a partial ordering. Your suggestion would require both the extra work of implementing an equality comparison, and the extra restriction of requiring equivalent objects to compare equal.